# Error on executing a stored procedure using While condition

Tags: c#

```
        SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(MyClass.GlobalConn());
        sqlConn.Open();

        try
        {
            string getAllBranch = "SELECT iBranch_num,LTRIM(RTRIM(sConstant)) FROM tblgobranch";
            SqlCommand cmdgetAllBranch = new SqlCommand(getAllBranch, sqlConn);
            SqlDataReader dRgetAllBranch=cmdgetAllBranch.ExecuteReader();



            while (dRgetAllBranch.Read())
            {

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.rvk_GetSalesPerItem", sqlConn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@piDateFrom", SqlDbType.Int).Value = FromDT1;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@piDateThru", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ToDT2;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@BRANCH", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = dRgetAllBranch[1].ToString();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@brNum", SqlDbType.Int).Value = dRgetAllBranch[0].ToString();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@PluCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = str1;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
```

I got error here

> *"There is already open data reader associated with this command"*

Please help me with this.

Comment: try to use a new Connection object every time you invoke rvkGetSalesPerItem SP.

Comment: What does `MyClass.GlobalConn` method do?

Comment: my connection string to connect to my Database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently executing a reader on your open connection (`SqlDataReader dRgetAllBranch=cmdgetAllBranch.ExecuteReader();`) while you attempt to execute a stored procedure on the same connection. That's the reason for the error.

Try this instead in your `while` loop

```
SqlConnection sqlConnStoredProc = new SqlConnection(MyClass.GlobalConn());
sqlConnStoredProc.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.rvk_GetSalesPerItem", sqlConnStoredProc);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.Add("@piDateFrom", SqlDbType.Int).Value = FromDT1;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@piDateThru", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ToDT2;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@BRANCH", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = dRgetAllBranch[1].ToString();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@brNum", SqlDbType.Int).Value = dRgetAllBranch[0].ToString();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@PluCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = str1;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

sqlConnStoredProc.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a new connection object to execute another command while reader is being used.

```
    SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(MyClass.GlobalConn());
    sqlConn.Open();

    try
    {
        string getAllBranch = "SELECT iBranch_num,LTRIM(RTRIM(sConstant)) FROM tblgobranch";
        SqlCommand cmdgetAllBranch = new SqlCommand(getAllBranch, sqlConn);
        SqlDataReader dRgetAllBranch=cmdgetAllBranch.ExecuteReader();




        while (dRgetAllBranch.Read())
        {
            using(var con = new SqlConnection(MyClass.GlobalConn()))
            {

            con.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.rvk_GetSalesPerItem", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@piDateFrom", SqlDbType.Int).Value = FromDT1;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@piDateThru", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ToDT2;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@BRANCH", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = dRgetAllBranch[1].ToString();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@brNum", SqlDbType.Int).Value = dRgetAllBranch[0].ToString();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@PluCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = str1;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need open connection in loop

```
while (dRgetAllBranch.Read())
        {

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.rvk_GetSalesPerItem", sqlConn);
            cmd.Connection.Open();  //Open
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@piDateFrom", SqlDbType.Int).Value = FromDT1;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@piDateThru", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ToDT2;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@BRANCH", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = dRgetAllBranch[1].ToString();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@brNum", SqlDbType.Int).Value = dRgetAllBranch[0].ToString();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@PluCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = str1;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Connection.Close();  //Close
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use only one SqlCommand only. Open before while loop, and close after loop.

```
SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(MyClass.GlobalConn());
    sqlConn.Open();

    try
    {
        string getAllBranch = "SELECT iBranch_num,LTRIM(RTRIM(sConstant)) FROM tblgobranch";
        SqlCommand cmdgetAllBranch = new SqlCommand(getAllBranch, sqlConn);
        SqlDataReader dRgetAllBranch=cmdgetAllBranch.ExecuteReader();


        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.rvk_GetSalesPerItem", sqlConn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Connection.Open();//open one time
        while (dRgetAllBranch.Read())
        {                
            cmd.parameters.Cler();//clear old parameter and add new
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@piDateFrom", SqlDbType.Int).Value = FromDT1;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@piDateThru", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ToDT2;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@BRANCH", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = dRgetAllBranch[1].ToString();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@brNum", SqlDbType.Int).Value = dRgetAllBranch[0].ToString();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@PluCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = str1;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        cmd.Connection.Close();//open one time
```